# How can I cite the subfigures in this form figure (a-c)

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I have formatted the subfigures in a figure as following

```
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfigure[]{\label{fig:sub:a} \includegraphics{...}}
  \subfigure[]{\label{fig:sub:b} \includegraphics{...}}
  \subfigure[]{\label{fig:sub:c} \includegraphics{...}}
  \caption {Three subfigures. (\textit{a})xxx, (\textit{b})xxx, and (\textit{c})xxx.}
  \label{multifigures}
\end{figure}
```

Now I want to cite the `multifigures` as figure (\textit{a}-\textit{c}), like figure 1 (*a*-*c*). That is, I want the letters are italic and surrounded by only one bracket with the figure number outside the bracket. I try `\ref{fig:sub:a}--\subref{fig:sub:c}`, but it gives me figure (a)-(c) with upright font and separate brackets surrounding each letter.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the obsolete `subfigure` package anymore. `subcaption` or `subfig` are the recommended packages in modern documents.

Comment: That should also give you, I think, options for labelling and references. But look at `cleverref` or `fref` for flexible cross-referencing.

Comment: I don't think that writing the cross-reference as "figure 1 (*a*-*c*)" is all that clear. In fact, if I were reading a paper and came across such a cross-reference, I would be quite uncertain as to what was being referenced. My recommendation is to write "figure 1" if you mean to cross-reference the entire figure, and to write "subfigures 1a-c" -- or, if you must, "subfigures (1a-c)" -- if the goal is to cross-reference a subset of the complete figure. For sure, I would *not* italicize the subfigure letters ("a" and "c") in the cross-reference *unless* they're also italicized in the captions.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a combination of using `cleveref` and `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}
% label is a, b ...
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}}


\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
% multiple refs are compressed to a range with the compress option
\usepackage[compress]{cleveref}

% define the subfigure ref class
\crefname{subfigure}{subfigure}{subfigures}
\Crefname{subfigure}{Subfigure}{Subfigures}
% this is the formatting command for the subfigure ranges:
% the important part is the \crefstripprefix which removes the
% figure number from the second label. #1 is the first label, #2 the second.
% the rest are start and end markers for the hyperlinks.
\crefrangelabelformat{subfigure}{(#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6)}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{All}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{test}
    \label{subfig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{test}
    \label{subfig:2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{test}
    \label{subfig:3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

See \cref{subfig:1,subfig:2,subfig:3}

\end{document}
```

This wouldn't work with italics, I do not know why. but if you redefine 
`\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\itshape\alph{subfigure}}`
The command \crefstripprefix throws an error.

Result:

[image: result]